# Vue2 v-bind not working properly on child instance?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I have a child instance of Vue and v-bind only works on the parent instance but not in the child one. I did a sample file to explain my issue.

Am I missing something?

This is my code:

```js
var app2 = new Vue({
  el: '#app2',
  data: {
    isSpinning2: true
  },
  methods: {
    stop2: function() {
      app2.isSpinning2 = false;
    }
  }
});

var app1 = new Vue({
  el: '#app1',
  data: {
    isSpinning: true
  },
  methods: {
    stop1: function() {
      app1.isSpinning = false;
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.2/vue.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div id="app1">
  <i v-bind:class="{'fa-spin': isSpinning}" class="fa fa-address-book"></i>
  <button v-on:click="stop1">Stop 1</button>
  <div id="app2">
    <i v-bind:class="{'fa-spin': isSpinning2}" class="fa fa-address-book"></i>
    <button v-bind:onclick="stop2">Stop 2</button>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: You can't nest Vue's in this way. The entire template will be treated as the `app1` template.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is exactly what components are for. Here is a component encapsulating your spinner buttons.

```js
console.clear()

Vue.component("spinner",{
  template: `
    <div>
      <i v-bind:class="{'fa-spin': isSpinning}" class="fa fa-address-book"></i>
      <button v-on:click="stop"><slot /></button>  
    </div>
  `,
  data(){
    return {
     isSpinning: true
    }
  },
  methods: {
    stop: function() {
      this.isSpinning = false;
    }
  }
})


var app1 = new Vue({
  el: '#app1',
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.2/vue.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div id="app1">
  <spinner>Stop 1</spinner>
  <spinner>Stop 2</spinner>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your response, so, would it be a good idea to create a component for a custom input control like a phone number input and add all the validation logic in the component?